# Formula for the size of the union of neighbourhoods in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

If $A,B \subseteq X$ and $|N(A)|=|A|$ and $|N(B)|=|B|$ in a finite bipartite graph $G$ with bipartition $X\cup Y$ then is it true that if Hall's condition holds on $X$ that:

$|N(A \cup B)|=|A \cup B|$ ?

It seems very obvious in my head, visually, but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Please help I'm very stuck

Comment: What is Hall's condition? What is X? What is N(A)? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hall's condition means the the neighbourhood of every subset of X is at least as big as the subset. I'm stuck because I know by using Hall's theorem that: $|A\cup B| \leqslant |N(A\cup B)|\leqslant |N(A)|+|N(B)|=|A|+|B|$ . But I don't know how to show it is equal to $|A\cup B$. Please could you help.

Comment: You'll need to look at $A \cap B$ as well.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?